# NestJS - Mongoose with GridFS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I want to use mongoose with NestJs. I'm using the package `@nestjs/mongoose` as describe in the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb).
It works correctly when I use it with standard models. But I need to use [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) to store files in my mongo database.

How could I use this feature? Is an integration available with `@nestjs/mongoose` to use third party libraries like [`mongoose-gridfs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-gridfs) or another one? 
Or should is use directly mongoose without `@nestjs/mongoose` in my `NestJs` application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For thoose who want to use mongoose with other package which needs connection, you shouldn't use the `@nestjs/module`. 
Here is an example to use standard mongoose library : https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/14-mongoose-base

Answer (score 1):

I used the @InjectConnection() decorator from the nestjs/mongoose package to achieve this functionality:

```
export class AttachmentsService {
  private readonly attachmentGridFsRepository: any; // This is used to access the binary data in the files
  private readonly attachmentRepository: Model<AttachmentDocument>; // This is used to access file metadata

  constructor(@InjectConnection() private readonly mongooseConnection: Mongoose,
              @Inject(Modules.Logger) private readonly logger: Logger) {
    this.attachmentGridFsRepository = gridfs({
      collection: 'attachments',
      model: Schemas.Attachment,
      mongooseConnection: this.mongooseConnection,
    });

    this.attachmentRepository = this.attachmentGridFsRepository.model;
  }
```

My connection is instantiated in the app.tsx using Mongoose.forRootAsync().